# Удаление локальных коммитов git

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

Есть три ветки: `master`, `test` и `test-n`.

В ветке `test` было сделано несколько коммитов, которые были отправлены в удаленный репозиторий, затем еще несколько, но не отправлены.
После этого ветке `test-n` было сделано все что нужно и отправлено на удаленный репозиторий.

Затем ветка `test` была удалена и из удаленного репозитория и из локального.

Но при попытке сделать `arc diff` он находит эти неотправленные коммиты в ветке `test` и предлагает добавить их в этот самый diff. Как избавиться от этих неотправленных коммитов?

Comment: что такое *arc diff*? добавьте эту информацию непосредственно в текст вопроса, нажав [edit].

Comment: `git gc --prune=now` убивает все осиротевшие листья и ветки. А если речь про удалённый репозиторий, то убедитесь, что вы действительно удалили локально копию удалённого бранча в индексе  с помощью `git remote update -p`.